# Card reader and usb flash drive not detected on Xfce4 on a Chromebook

Tags: usb, xfce, chromebook

Whenever I insert a card reader, it appears then disappears after a few seconds. When I unplug it, it appears but highlighted. So I just can't access my memorycard reader in Xfce4 Linux, but when in ChromeOS everything works just fine. What should I do?

Comment: How is the card reader connected to the computer? Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lsusb` (for USB) or `lspci` (for PCI/internal) with the card reader connected and `sudo lsblk -f` with a card inserted into it? Thanks.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Answer (score 1):

i wasnt able to solve the ploblem completely but i have been able to access my removable devices via oppening a certain folder let me walk you through on how to get to the folder

**fist step**
-go to the system file folders 
**second step**
-find the folder called media
-where as in this folder you will find a folder called **removable** and from that folder make a shortcut to that folder in the desktop and then open the folder and there you go you can access your removable devices from the folder.